# I wrote a new X11 keyboard layout file, how do I get my system to recognize it?

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, xorg, dvorak

I like to configure my keys my way, so I wrote a keyboard symbols file and I put it in

```
`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/cat`
```

I use it by running `setxkbmap cat -variant dvorak` (and it works), but it doesn't show up in the console configuration (`dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`) nor in the Gnome keyboard settings... nor anywhere else, so I have to run `setxkbmap` every time.

I suppose that I have to register it somewhere, but where?

Answer (score 4):

Ah, for Gnome to recognize it I had to add it to:

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/{base,evdev}.{xml,lst}
```

Comment: I could solve it like this, too. But I hate editing system managed files manually. If there is a better way, I'd love to know.

Comment: Modifying evdev.xml was sufficient for me under Ubuntu 19.10.